# Unable to connect to mongodb atlas using compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

Trying to connect to mongodb atlas but the page keeps loading after i click on connect button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is to check if your ISP allows connection to the server. I had similar issue and the reason was the port was blocked. It was unblocked after a request.

Comment: How can I check if my ISP allows connectiong to the mongodb atlas ?

Comment: You call them and check. Sometimes ISP block certain ports by default for security.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not have mongoDb installed.